# I don't understand this $D = R \cdot T.$ word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Exercise word problem:

*Hamilton rode his bike downhill 12 miles on the river trail from his house to the ocean and then rode uphill to return
home. His uphill speed was 8 miles per hour slower than his downhill speed. It took him 2 hours longer to get home than
it took him to get to the ocean. Find Hamilton’s downhill speed.*

$\dfrac {12}{R-8}=\dfrac {12}{R}+2$

What I don't understand in this textbook explanation is how it is determined (or what is the reasoning behind) where to put the $+2$ in the equation.

***Explanation in Openstax Elementary Algebra:***
*

> He took 2 hours longer uphill than downhill. The uphill time is 2 more
> than the downhill time.

- 

[the explanation in the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cRGx.png).

*Source: Elementary Algebra OpenStax Chapter 8*

I don't understand how you can know where to put the $+2$ in

In this exercise which deals with the same type of problem [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAHwI.png).

*Hudson travels 1080 miles in
a jet and then 240 miles by car to
get to a business meeting. The jet
goes 300 mph faster than the rate
of the car, and the car ride takes
1 hour longer than the jet. What is
the speed of the car?*

$\dfrac {1080}{R+300}=\dfrac {240}{R}$

I don't understand how to translate the car taking one hour longer than the jet into the equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain the problem in your words, and tell what do you understand by that

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images. Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You have taken pictures of an exercise in a textbook, without citing the text (author, title, etc.) or using your own words to describe what the exercise is about.  Indeed one part of that exercise is "Write a word sentence about the time."  Your perfunctory approach to asking will seem to many Readers to reflect a lack of interest or effort on your part, and will likely lead to voting that closes the Question.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is $D=RT$, but they're using it as $T=\frac{D}{R}$.

The downhill speed is $R$ and the distance it $12$, so the time
to go downhill is $T = 12/R$.   The uphill speed is $R-8$ and the
distance is $12$, so the time to go uphill is $T=12/(R-8)$.  The
problem tells you that this second time is $2$ more than first time.
That is

$$\frac{12}{R-8} = \frac{12}{R} + 2.$$

Or

$$\mbox{uphill time} = \mbox{downhill time} +2.$$

In your second problem, there is a missing $+1.$  You should have

$$\mbox{jet time} +1 = \mbox{car time.}$$

Comment: But Isn't the second time uphill $\frac{12}{R-8}$, and therefore shouldn't it be $\frac{12}{R-8} + 2 = \frac{12}{R} .$ ?

Comment: No.  Which of the times should be 2 more than the other?

Comment: ''He took 2 hours longer uphill than downhill. The uphill time is 2 more than the downhill time.''

It says he took 2 hours longer uphill. This part of the equation is uphill : $\frac{12}{R-8}$. 

Shouldn't that be $+ 2$?

Comment: Which is larger $1/(x+2)$ or $1/x$?

Comment: $1/x$  is larger

Comment: So which one should I add, say, 3 to, to make them equal.

Comment: Wouldn't adding 3 to one, make them unequal?

Comment: They're already unequal.  You said $1/x$ is larger.  If I say $1/x$ is three more than $1/(x+2)$ then you make them equal by adding three to the smaller one.